# Classification algorithm for multi-touch screen

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, computational-geometry, classification

What is the algorithm can be used to resolve the following classification problem?
We have Multi-touch screen, user that can touch it with two or three fingers simultaneously.

1. After user touches screen, we remember initial positions of his fingers. Each fingers gets a group of coordinates from the device.
2. When user moves fingers we should track movements of his fingers.

The problem is that when fingers move close to each other. How to determine which points to which finger belongs?

I know this is a some kind of classification problem. What is an algorithm can be used to approach this problem?

Comment: If you keep track of finger movements all the time, then I can't see the problem - you just read coordinates of finders, say, each millisecond and then find nearest point among previous finger positions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I described the problem more carefully. Please, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519477/tracking-multi-touch-movements-inside-the-frame-with-transmitters-and-receivers

Answer (score 2):

One problem is to start with reports of N locations at time t and reports of N locations at time t+1 and work out that position 1 at time t is the same finger as position 3 at time t+1. The military have looked at this sort of thing a lot, often under the name of data fusion. One approach is to write down a cost of associating position i at time t with position j at time t+1 and then find the permutation with minimum total cost - this is an instance of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem.

If the device in fact reports two fingers very close together as one, you have a more complex problem - but you surely don't have many different positions to consider, so you should be able to e.g. try various ways of treating one position report as two different reports and then pick the highest scoring possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the assignment problem is overkill for this, given that you are trying to assign three points to three fingers. Even if you are trying to assign five points to five fingers, you are better off using a brute force approach to figuring out the optimal configuration of points to fingers. Note that for three fingers and three points, there are only six possible unique assignments of fingers to points. So it's best to just calculate the cost of each assignment configuration and choose the one with least cost.

However, I think this is missing the point of your question. The tricky part is not the assignment process itself, but choosing a decent "cost" function for each possible assignment. If the cost function doesn't take account of prior finger-point assignments, then there's an equal cost to assigning any finger to any point and so you lack any "continuity" where fingers are assigned to the same moving point.

So your goal is to ensure your assignment models 'real life'. The approach I suggest is this:

Define a physical model for the movement of fingers. A very simple model would be a momentum  model where each finger is independent of each other and is assumed to have some inertia. If a finger moves dx,dy in one frame, you would expect it to move dx,dy in the second frame. This gives you an expectation value for where you expect the finger to be next. Now you can define the cost of assigning a finger to a point as some function of the distance between the location of the actual point registered and where you expected it to be.

Sum up the costs for each finger-point assignment and find the configuration with lowest cost.

Now, if you want to be more sophisticated, all you have to do is use a more sophisticated model. Perhaps you don't want to assume fingers move independently. You might want to expect some correlation between the finger movements. In which case, refine the model, calculate the new point expectations and calculate the cost of the assignment as before.